# Use class name from .css file in <style> section

Tags: css

**Scenario**

I have a .CSS file with a pre-defined style. I have linked this in my HTML file. I want to assign one particular class name (myclass) to all TD elements in the html file.

**Question**

How can I assign the class name (myclass) to all TDs in the document without doing `class="myclass"` for each TD elements.

Can I reference a class name in `<style>` section

**Intention**
To reduce repetition of `class='myclass'`

i.e

myCss.css has below

```
.myclass{text-weight:bold;}
}
```

I use this CSS ( I cannot modify the above CSS file).
Is it possible to use as below in a seperate HTML file which refere above .css file

```
<style>
TD : myclass (or something)
</style>
```

if it is possible then i can avoid using `<td class='myclass'></td>`

Comment: then u dont use a class. Wrap all the possible locations of td in a class then use .ur-class td selector in ur css

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
td{
 //Put content  of myclass here
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dh2hntd9/2/)**

You can see in demo that TDs don't have any class name.

Comment: yes ,its a good suggestion , but its a repetetion , is there a way to inherit

Comment: I think you're not familiar with CSS concept, if you want to add style to each `td` it's the best optimized way, when you're saying `repetition` maybe you're concerned about performance. But it's not a real concern :)

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/76gx6akr/

```
<table>
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.myclass{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

js

```
$( "td" ).addClass( "myclass" );
```

Comment: This is not what i want, I wanted to reduce the repetition

Comment: @NuwanDammika where is the repetition what i mean is to use class if u require different styling for diff tables else directly write css for `td` tag

Comment: one more option is to do `$( "td" ).addClass( "myclass" );`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add styles to all td element, you can modify the td element directly:

```
td{
}
```

You could also add myclass on the tr in your table then use subclasses. In this case an id to only modify thing with .myclass & td.

```
.myclass td{
    /* stuff */
}


<table>
    <tr class="myclass">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>More Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in which you can do some interesting styles at a high level. For example, you can declare a global style using

```
td {
    background: red;
}
```

This will apply style to all `td` elements within your document. But what if you want to be more precise? Perhaps you want styles for a `td` which is a direct child of a certain element. If so, you can try the following

```
.example tr > td {
    background: blue;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with some more examples. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9hroqwm/1/).